# php can't read session value

Tags: php, session

I'm working with a login.php page.
when users login successfully, system will save their usernames into session.like below code:

```
if ($user != null) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user["username"];
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user["id"];
    return 0;
}
```

Then the page will be located to main.php.
Main.php will read the session, like below code:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) == false || empty($_SESSION['username']))
{
    // transfer into login page
}
else
{
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

The main page can't read the $_SESSION['username'], the value is null.
What should I do now?

Comment: Did you put `session_start();` on top of the page where you `SET` the session values. i.e. login.php ?

Comment: what var_dump($_SESSION) returns?

Comment: if (!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username']))

Comment: try  var_dump($_SESSION) before and after SET session values on Login.php file and see what it show.

Comment: Your code is incomplete $user will always be null

Comment: what is result of var_dump($user) ? Maybe it is empty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `session_start()` at the `$user` check condition page.

```
session_start();
if ($user != null)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user["username"];
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user["id"];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: From the code, $user will always be NULL, the upper code is missing!

Comment: @WaqarAlamgir how can you say so.?? or you can say might be $user is null

Comment: It works.Is there any shortcut for not writing "session_start()" everywhere? Currently,I write this code in a included file.

Comment: @roast_soul yes you can make one common file which used in every page and include it in index.php file so you don't need to write it over and over again

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar:but I have to include it over and over.

Comment: @roast_soul yah you need to thats why i said common file which are not need to include over and over just one time and there you go with it

Comment: since it is not defined it will always be NULL

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar: A common file that writes "session_start()" ? I think it should be included when we need to use session? What's your meaning for no need to include over and over? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @roast_soul just like database connection file do you include it in every page just include it once and you can access database from everywhere just like that put session_start at same file or other...

Comment: @Dipesh Parmar:Yes, I include my DBHelper file where I need to operate the DB. So the include_once('DBHelper.php') sentence appears in most pages. So can I　avoid to write include_once('DBHelper.php') where I　need to operate DB.

Answer (score 1):

You Must add `session_start()` when you use SESSION variable

```
session_start(); //at the beginning of file 

if ($user != null) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];
    return 0;
}
```

and then

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    // transfer into login page
}
else
{
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to user session variable. you must start session before use session variable.

```
session_start();
if ($user != null) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user["username"];
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user["id"];
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if (count($user)>0 and is_array($user)) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user["username"];
    $_SESSION['userid'] = $user["id"];

}
```